# angular 2, return Observables according to if statement

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

Hi I want create something like this.

```
someFunction():Observable<Response>{
  let response$ = new Observerable();

  if (...){
    response$ = this.http.get(url1)
  }else{
    response$ = this.http.get(url2)
  }
  return response$
}
```

if I subscribe to it, i'm getting an error

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Thanks for all the help in advance!

EDIT---------
this is the actual function using ionic 2 and cordova.
It checks whether the app is on a mobile device or not and opens a popup with url (intend to be used for social logins)

Once the window closed I will need to perfom a http.get request to fetch a token from my backend.

```
public social(providerName:string):Observable<Response>{

let response$ = new Observable<Response>();
let url =providerName+'/someUrl'

let authWindow;

if(window.cordova){
    let authWindow= InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no');

    authWindow.addEventListener('loadstop', event => {
        if(event.url.indexOf(`${providerName}/callback`) > -1){
            authWindow.close()
        }
    });

    authWindow.addEventListener('loaderror', event =>{
        if(event.url.indexOf(`${providerName}/callback`) > -1){
            authWindow.close()
        }
    });

    authWindow.addEventListener('exit', () => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
             response$ = this.http.get(...)
        },500)
    })

}else{
    authWindow = createWindow(popupUrl);
    let window = Observable.interval(1000);

    let  pingWindow = window.subscribe(
        ()=>{
            if(authWindow.closed){
                pingWindow.unsubscribe();

                response$ = this.http.get(...)

            }
        })
}

return response$
```

}

Comment: Sounds like a problem outside of the code you provided.

Comment: so you are saying that this syntax normal should work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this shouldn't lead to the error you got. I think the error is somewhere else.

Comment: I've posted the original function,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update reveals the problem.
You are not assigning to `response$` directly but in async callbacks. When `return response$` is executed, none of the assignments to `response$`

```
    setTimeout(()=>{
         response$ = this.http.get(...)
    },500)
```

nor

```
let  pingWindow = window.subscribe(
    ()=>{
        if(authWindow.closed){
            pingWindow.unsubscribe();

            response$ = this.http.get(...)

        }
    })
```

were executed yet.

The 1st is executed 0.5s later, the 2nd when the function passed to  `window.subscribe(...)` is executed because of an emitted value which will be at *some* point later.

```
public social(providerName:string):Observable<Response>{

    let response$ = new Subject<Response>();
    let url =providerName+'/someUrl'

    let authWindow;

    if(window.cordova){
        let authWindow= InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no');

        authWindow.addEventListener('loadstop', event => {
            if(event.url.indexOf(`${providerName}/callback`) > -1){
                authWindow.close()
            }
        });

        authWindow.addEventListener('loaderror', event =>{
            if(event.url.indexOf(`${providerName}/callback`) > -1){
                authWindow.close()
            }
        });

        authWindow.addEventListener('exit', () => {
            setTimeout(()=>{
                 this.http.get(...)
                 .map(val => val.json())
                 .subscribe(val => response$.next(val);
            },500)
        })

    }else{
        authWindow = createWindow(popupUrl);
        let window = Observable.interval(1000);

        let  pingWindow = window.subscribe(
            ()=>{
                if(authWindow.closed){
                    pingWindow.unsubscribe();

                    this.http.get(...)
                    .map(val => val.json())
                    .subscribe(val => response$.next(val);
                }
            })
    }

    return response$.asObservable()
}
```

This should fix at least your immediate problem.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, i understand the issue now.
However in your suggestion, response$ would need to be a Subject right?
Otherwise .next wouldn't be possible?

Comment: Hi Günter, I'm getting a strange behavior when I subscribe to this code, but only in cordova context. There some code in the callback is executed only every 2nd time.
I've posted the question, could you please have a look?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385268/ionic-2-cordova-inappbrowser-subscribing-to-observableresponse-messing-up-ev

Comment: Sorry, no idea.